# how to change bluetooth iap mode to spp mode in star micronics sm-t300i?

Tags: android, ios, printing

So, I've a sm-t300i and I want to use with Android device but I can't do it becuase the bluetooth printer is on iAP mode (IOS compatibility) and I need change to SPP mode.

Answer (score 2):

Well I solved this.
To change the settings on the printer, you need to hold down the feed and power button at the same time until it enters setup mode. Once in setup mode, press the power button to go through the modes. The three modes are: Bluetooth, UART and Bluetooth (iAP). Once you’re on the mode you want, press both buttons down again to confirm the settings

Comment: There is a catch here with my printer. The button will get stuck if we try this multiple times (at least with the model I have). From then onwards, long pressing both buttons for some time just prints the printer settings. It seem to bypass the setup mode. Terrible experience